# Can AppService connections cause application to be suspended?

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

So I have a question about a specific behavior I observed on a project I'm working on. I'm working on UWP with Unity. I can't share the code, but the question is more about the way windows deals with apps and appservices.

So I have two applications, A and B. A is your standard UWP application, B is UWP too, but generated by Unity (I don't know if it changes anything). Also B is an Hololens applciation. Everything I describe  is working on Hololens V1.

My goal was for A to launch B. Due to some old design decisions, we used App Servcies to communicate between the two. So in the code I had, A established an AppService connection toward B. In the background, B used Toast notifications to activate itself. When activated, B also establishes an AppService toward A (but a new one actually). During my tests, I had Visual Studio connected to A, and everything was working fine.

However when I detached the debugger from A, I observed the behavior I want to understand. If I start A, with no debugger attached, and launch B, then a few seconds later (after B has taken the foreground), both applications will be suspended. I see now that the Visual debugger was blocking the application A from suspending.

I thought at first it was maybe the Toast activation. However the problem also occurs if A establishes an appservice connection and if I start B by myself. I see the causality because if I ask for an execution extension in OnSuspend in A, then B will also have an extension.

So my question is : Why is that happening ? What happens when you create an Appservice connection toward an already-running application ?

For now I sidestepped the problem by removing any AppService connection in A and launching B via Protocol.